# form submit ajax zend framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, output

I am trying to learn how to work with ajax in zf 1, but i have run into a trouble. I have a simple form and I am posting its value to the controller index, and then want to return the message I have sent and output in in the div with class="show-msg", but it doesn't seem to be working. I have a php error that says that undefined index 'message'.Could somebody please help me.
my jquery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#form").submit(function() {
    var message = $('#login').val();
    $.post('/index',{'message':message},function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        $('.show-msg').html(data)
    });
  return false;                      
  });     
});
```

then my controller

```
public function init()
{

    $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('admin');

    $contentSwitch = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $contentSwitch->addActionContext('ajax',array('json'))
                    ->initContext();

}

public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_Test();
    $this->view->form = $form;
    $form->setAction('index')
         ->setMethod('post');

    $myArrayofData = array('a','b','c');
    if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        $msg = $this->_request->getPost();
        echo $msg['message'];
    }
```

form is being created a framework's way through a model and it's action and methods are ok.Request is being send, but as a response a get a full html page source code instead of json format.

**NOTE:EDITED**

Answer (score 0):

`message` is not defined in your jQuery code `{'message':message}`. Try

```
$.post('admin/index',{'message':$('#message').val()},function(...
```

I also see an error in your ajax context. It should be

```
$contentSwitch->addActionContext('index','json')
    ->initContext();
```

in the `indexAction` return results in json format:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

If your intention is to respond always in json from the index action, I recommend you to use the json helper and not to use the ajax context: Get rid of $contentSwitch and finish the index action with

```
$this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);
```

Use contexts when you want to return in different formats from the same action.

Comment: I have modified my controller to:
    
     public function indexAction()
     {
     $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
     //$this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);
     echo json_encode($data['message']);
    }

and my jquery code:
      $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#form").submit(function() {
  var message = $('#message').val();
        $.post('admin/index',{'message':message},function(data){
         console.log(data);
        });
      return false;                      
     });     
    });
but when i try to console.log(data), i get nothing

Comment: Do you use firebug? You can see the request and the response in the `net` tab. Do you see php is receiving the `message` as a post parameter? Do you see `$data` in the response?

Comment: I also wonder whether you have your controller correctly setup. Shouldn't `$.post('admin/index',...)` be `$.post('/admin/index',...)`. Is you controller called AdminController? Do you have an `admin` layout? If you respond in json format you don't need a layout. Have you tried to submit on a non-ajax context, for instance with `curl -d 'message=test%20message' http://yourserver/admin/index`?. Once you are sure the backend is returning what you expect, debug the ajax call in the frontend.

Comment: I have used tips that you have given me, and the post is being send now(fixed it), but it returns me the page html code. and below my div where i want to display data it echo's null

Comment: If you receive html code is because the layout and template are rendered. If you leave init() method empty and you return with `return $this->_helper->json->sendJson($data)` from the indexAction, you should be right. The `json` helper will deactivate rendering (you can do it also manually by calling `$this->_helper->_viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);`)